# Rectangle doesn't center

Tags: html, css, button, centering

EDIT: Oh and I tried margin but I want it to be responsive and to stick along the with the title when viewed from different screens

Sorry, it may be a simple question but I can't get it to work
I'm trying to center a text with in a rectangle that tells in which category the article is in
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXxGR.png

Jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/bwpyypza/

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.section {
    background-color: rgb(202, 0, 0);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 25px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50%;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-family: open-sans;
}
```

```html
<hr>
    <div class="section">PARENTING</div>
    <h1>Title of the Article</h1>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.section {
    background-color: rgb(202, 0, 0);
    padding: 10px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50%;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-family: open-sans;
}
```

```html
<hr>
    <div class="section">PARENTING</div>
    <h1>Title of the Article</h1>
<hr>
```

Try this

Comment: @ekclone With this solution, the rectangle width isn't automatically computed from the size of the text, which means you have to manually set the size for each rectangle, and it will break if you change the font...

Comment: @dystroy yes I noticed that too, so I just completly removed the font-family line

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your section with in a div:

**html**

```
<hr>
<div id="sectionCont">
    <div class="section">PARENTING</div>
</div>
 <h1>Title of the Article</h1>

<hr>
```

And then use `text-align: center`

**css**

```
#sectionCont {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bwpyypza/2/)

Answer (score 1):

As your rectangle is defined as `inline-block`, the simplest and most consistent would be to set `text-align:center` in the container:

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.section {
    background-color: rgb(202, 0, 0);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 25px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50%;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-family: open-sans;
}
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
<hr>
    <div class="section">PARENTING</div>
    <h1>Title of the Article</h1>
<hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wish I could give everyone a upvote but I still don't have the reputation to do so

Answer (score 1):

All you need is small changes like this:

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.section {
 text-align: center;
}
.section span {
    background-color: rgb(202, 0, 0);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 25px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50%;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-family: open-sans;
}
```

```html
<hr>
    <div class="section"><span>PARENTING</span></div>
    <h1>Title of the Article</h1>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Modify your css file for following code snippet

.section {
    background-color: rgb(202, 0, 0);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 25px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50%;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-family: open-sans;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: and remove margin:25px from css

Comment: It doesn't center the button :/